# Error loading oci8.so with Ubuntu server 17.04 php 7 and apache2

Tags: php, oracle, php-7, ubuntu-server, oracle-call-interface

I have gone through the whole process of downloading Oracle instant client, SDK, etc. in a Ubuntu Server 17.04. Then converted rpm packages to deb with alien, installed, set the paths, downloaded pecl oci8, compiled and installed (w/o errors), etc. and then added the line:

extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/oci8.so

And restarted. When I check the /var/log/apache2/error.log I see:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/oci8.so' - libmql1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[Thu Jul 20 10:46:44.352631 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 23450] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Jul 20 10:46:44.352717 2017] [core:notice] [pid 23450] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Does any one know what I could do to make it work?
I guess I have not selinux enabled or maybe it is a permissions problem?

Thanks

Comment: FYI I've added the extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/oci8.so to the etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini and then did php --ri oci8 and all worked great. I could even run from command line the .php connection test and worked great. http://storage5.static.itmages.com/i/17/0721/h_1500638035_7713301_686b726cdf.jpeg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to put the ORACLE global variables NOT in /etc/environment but in the /etc/apache2/envvars

So, I've added these 2 lines at the end of /etc/apache2/envvars

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64
```

And all working great

Comment: the export of LD_LIBRARY_PATH was what I was missing apparently. Did that and the issue went away. Thanks +1

Comment: This should be marked as answer. For some reason on 16.04 this step wasn't needed.

Comment: This is the right answer. Worked for me too.

Answer (score 2):

As you still will have the same problem with php cli with the above solution, it would be better to add a new file /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf with this content:

```
/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib
```

Then run

```
sudo ldconfig
```

This way it works for apache and php cli and you do not need to change /etc/apache2/envvars

Answer (score 2):

With Linux Ubuntu 18, if you're getting the same message, but its command line version:
`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20170718/oci8'` when using php cli (= command line, as opposed to php as an apache module), all you need to do is to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (not ORACLE_HOME), inside of `/etc/environment`, as shown below:

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2`

Next time you open a shell, the environment will declare this variable.

Note that the variable value needs to point to the folder that contains the lib*.so files.

Verification:
open a new console, and run
`php -m | grep oci8`