# How to enable oci8 for PHP7.2 on Ubuntu18.10

Tags: php, oracle, apache, laravel-5, oracle-call-interface

I am following the [this](https://gist.github.com/Yukibashiri/cebaeaccbe531665a5704b1b34a3498e) link to enable the `oci8` extension for me but I still don't see the `oci8` extension enabled in my phpinfo. Any help or step by step guide would be appreciated.
I am using PHP7.2 as a service, apache2.4, on Ubuntu18.10 with oracle 11gR2 installed on my local as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one enable the OCI8 PHP extension, using the Oracle Instant Client, in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with PHP-FPM and NGINX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50396992/how-does-one-enable-the-oci8-php-extension-using-the-oracle-instant-client-in)

Comment: Tried this already, doesn't work